# when ever i change interstitial ID to the one on Admob and i try to test the app on my phone

Tags: java, android, admob, mobile-application, interstitial

whenever I change interstitial ID to the one on AdMob and I try to test the app on my phone it is showing me this message on the screen, unfortunately, the app has been stopped please what to do about this ??
and here is the code I used to  implement the ads who works great for testing but when i change its ID the app is not working and the indroid studio is not showing any errors just a message that the installation is successfully completed so any thoughs

> JAVA

```
    //View adContainer = findViewById(R.id.unitads);
        final String packageName = this.getPackageName();
        context = this;
        linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.unitads);
        admob.admobBannerCall(this, linearlayout);
        
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(SettingsClass.Interstitial);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();
        
        rateus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rateus2);
        shareapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.play2);
        
        rateus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AppRater.rateLink(MainActivity.this);
                 
            }
        });
        
        shareapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShareApp();
            }
        });
        
        mDBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
      //got it from here
        //Check exists database
        File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.DBNAME);
        if(false == database.exists()) {
            mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Copy db
            if(copyDatabase(this)) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error"+DataBaseHelper.DBLOCATION, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        //Get product list in db when db exists
        mItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        mItemList.clear();
        mItemList.addAll(mDBHelper.getListItem());
        //Init adapter
        adapter = new ListItemAdapter(this, mItemList);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        //Set adapter for listview
        try {
            lvItem.setAdapter(adapter);
        }catch (Exception ex){}
        //itemSelected();
    }
    
    private void ShareApp(){
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "Hey my friend check out this app\n https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+ getPackageName() +" \n";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
    
    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DataBaseHelper.DBNAME);
            String outFileName = DataBaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DataBaseHelper.DBNAME;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.w("SplashActivity","DB copied");
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AppRater.app_launched(this);
    }
   
    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
         mInterstitialAd.loadAd(ConsentSDK.getAdRequest(context));
    } 
  /*
    private void itemSelected() {
        
        lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             Item itemClicked = mItemList.get(position) ;
                
                try {
                    //Class classe= Class.forName(getPackageName()+".Details");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Details.class);
                    intent.putExtra("detail",""+itemClicked.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("title",""+itemClicked.getTitle());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    //finish();
                    if(admob.mCount == admob.nbShowInterstitial) {
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) 
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                            admob.mCount=0;
                    }
                    ++admob.mCount;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             
            };
        });
    }
*/
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        if ((mItemList.get(position) instanceof Item)) {
            Item itemClicked = (Item) mItemList.get(position);
            try {

                //Class classe= Class.forName(getPackageName()+".Details");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("detail", "" + itemClicked.getText());
                intent.putExtra("title", "" + itemClicked.getTitle());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                //startActivity(intent);
                //finish();
                if (admob.mCount == admob.nbShowInterstitial) {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    admob.mCount = 0;
                }
                ++admob.mCount;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void guide(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button12:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data_one.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
                break;
            case R.id.button13:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data_two.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button14:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data_three.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data_four.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data_five.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data_six.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Data_seven.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
        }

}
}
```

Comment: share your code which you used to implement the ads

Comment: I just did add the implemented code

Comment: and what is the error you re gettinng ?

Comment: i didn't get any error android studio shows that the installation is successfully completed but when the app starts on the phone it shuts down quickly and the ''unfortunately, the app has been stopped'' message shows up

Comment: when the app shuts down , it will a show an error message in the logcat , thats the error to paste here

Comment: it shows absolutely nothing bro just successful install message

Comment: i was working recently on showing ads on my app but i guess admob dosn't allow you to show real ads when app is still in developement mode , so you can test using a test key , secondly make sure you you include the metadata in your manifst , in your admob two keys are generated the first one is to set up in your activity code , and the second one is to add in your manifest file meta data , did you implement these steps ?

Comment: i didn't know about these two admob keys i just create a banner and an interstitial and copied their IDs, can you please tell me more about the two keys or just leave a youtube video link here if you don't mind

Comment: check my answer below , if it still dosnt work let me know

Comment: So i tried what you told me to do but Still not working man :(

Comment: did you try a test key ? or the key you got from admob?

Comment: The key i got from admob of course

Comment: well i said it might not work so the ad won't show , for someone reason google dosnt allow to show real ads when app is in developement mode , save your admob key somewhere and try with this key , it is test key from google ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 , put this one instead of the real one and tell me if it works

Comment: yes it works fine with that key

Comment: Yeah i guess my point is clear now , i tried to add ads on my app before as well and i read that somehow admob dosn't allow you to use real key while app is still in developement mode , so in my case the ads started showing only after uploading my app to google play store , hope this is clear

Comment: so how can i add the real key to the app when it is already uploaded to google play?

Comment: can i just add the key and upload the app without knowing that is working?

Comment: i did all i can to make it work before on my app , i tried many things but eventually had to surrender and upload my app to google play , after that it started working , but certainly the key generated from admob they work

Comment: so i will upload it to google play then hopefully it works thank you so much bro

Comment: thatts my pleasure buddy

Answer (score 0):

To interstinal Ads to your app , follow these steps

- First of all add the google play for ads library to your dependencies gradle

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'`

- Secondly you should generate keys from your admob after selecting the desire ad , two keys will generated the one has a / and other has ~

- The one with the slash , You add in your code

  ```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(SettingsClass.Interstitial); /// here the one with slash
  ```

- Thirdly in your manifest file , add the meta data with has the key with ~

```
<manifest>
   <application>
       <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
           android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/> // the one with ~
   </application>
</manifest>
```

PS : real keys might not work in developement mode , i guess google stopped that , so they will run after uploading your app to google play store